# How to make a word break for span element?

Tags: css, checkout-page

I would like to add a word break at the checkout page via custom CSS but I'm not getting an expected result.

**1. I have a heading like below:**

[image]

**2. I would like to change it as below:**

[image]

**3. But getting the below result:**

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<span class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Contact Person/Delivery Recipient'">Kontaktperson/Leveransmottagare</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.xxxxx {
        word-wrap: break-word;
        display:block;
        width:156px;
    }
```

Could anyone please help me to get the desired result?

Comment: did you try my answer below?

Comment: @magefms Yes, I have tried but that's not working.

Comment: why it is .xxxxx? is that the actual code?

Comment: @magefms No, it's not an actual code. The actual code is <div class="contact-delivery-title">
        <span class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Contact Person / Delivery Recipient'">Kontaktperson / Leveransmottagare</span>
      </div>
So I have put the class name .contact-delivery-title .step-title which is in .xxxxx

Comment: no not like that, you can do it like `span.step-title`

Comment: check updated answer it should like that

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to Magento, it is a CSS only question.

Answer (score 0):

*Use BR Tag*

```
<span class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Contact Person/Delivery Recipient'">Kontaktperson/<br>Leveransmottagare</span>
```

not need to add css for word break for span element

Comment: I don't want to edit the html file. I just want to have this result via CSS. Since I need this output only in the mobile device.

Comment: so need  add space Kontaktperson/   Leveransmottagare like this otherwise not possible what you need

Comment: this is like a full paragraph Kontaktperson/Leveransmottagare so not possible what you need

Comment: Thanks for your information!

Comment: It's my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to find and replace the text with a word-break, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115152/jquery-find-and-replace-string) for reference:

```
$(".step-title").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    text = text.replace("Kontaktperson/Leveransmottagare", "Kontaktperson/<wbr>Leveransmottagare");
    $(this).text(text);
});
```

[Here](https://daily-dev-tips.com/posts/using-the-shy-soft-hyphen-in-html/) you find some more information about `<wbr>`.

Answer (score -1):

Please try with this

value normal / initial -    Break words only at allowed break points

break-word - Allows unbreakable words to be broken

```
.xxxxx {
    word-wrap: normal;
    display:block;
    width:156px;
}
```

Comment: I have tried it but not working

Comment: Please have you checked your CSS code updated in browser?

Comment: Yes, I have checked and see the CSS code updated in browser but I didn't get the desired result.